# Proper way to use get_the_content() in front-page.php and the content-home.php?

Tags: templates, the-content

```
<div class="class1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="class2">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="class3">
                <a href="">category</a>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 70 ); ?> </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above is an excerpt that is kept on `content-home.php`

This is the correct version or correct coding practice →

```
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 70 ); ?>
```

or this one ***w/o*** the `<p></p>` tag →

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 70 ); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the question here?

Comment: My question is <p></p> tag is automaticall fetched when we run this → <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 70 ); ?> 
  or It is advised that we should incorporate the dynamic code within <p></p> tag.

Comment: you can also just use "get_the_excerpt()" this way, you can write a precise short text explaining it better than just a cut off version of the content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To output your content, It is advised that you pass your content through a filter. `get_the_content()` does not do this, so it will not for example execute shortcodes or create `<p>` tags.

So, it would be better to use it this way:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( get_the_content() , 70 ) ); ?>
```

You can also pass the `$before` and `$after` arguments to your title. This is a simple example of how to do so:

```
<?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>
```

Which will output this:

```
<h1>Your Title Here</h1>
```

It's possible to pass variables or functions too. Take a look at this example:

```
<?php the_title('<h1><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">','</a></h1>'); ?>
```

This will create a link of your title and wrap it in a header tag:

```
<h1><a href="some path here">Your Title Here</a></h1>
```

You might want to take a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute) codex page for additional information about `the_title_attribute()` too.