# where to apply "apply filters" and other Sanitization Functions

Tags: filters, sanitization

I got to learn something new today here on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274732/proper-way-to-use-get-the-content-in-front-page-php-and-the-content-home-php).

I have code written for a Post widget →

```
        <?php
    class chimp_post_widget extends WP_Widget {
        function __construct() {
            //Create Widget
            parent::__construct(
                'post_display_widget',
                esc_html__('The Post Widget','simplisto'),
                array(
                    'classname'       =>    'post-widget',
                    'description'     =>    esc_html__('A Post Thumbnail Widget', 'simplisto' )
                )
            );
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $number_of_posts = isset( $instance['number_of_posts'] ) ? absint( $instance['number_of_posts'] ) : 5;
        $number_of_words = isset( $instance['number_of_words'] ) ? absint( $instance['number_of_words'] ) : 20;

        $cat_include = isset( $instance['cat_include'] ) ? $instance['cat_include'] : '';
        $cat_exclude = isset( $instance['cat_exclude'] ) ? $instance['cat_exclude'] : '';

        $vertical_sidebar_check =  isset( $instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) && ( 'on' === $instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) ? 'on' : 'off';
        ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'simplisto' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number_of_posts' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of projects to show:', 'simplisto' ); ?></label>
        <input class="tiny-text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number_of_posts' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number_of_posts' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="<?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number_of_words' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Set the word limit for project descriptions:', 'simplisto' ); ?></label>
        <input class="tiny-text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number_of_words' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number_of_words' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="<?php echo $number_of_words; ?>" size="4" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat_include' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Include Categories:', 'simplisto' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat_include' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cat_include' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat_include ); ?>" />
        <small>Comma separated list of category IDs to <strong>include</strong> in post query. e.g.: 11,17,347<br>If blank, all categories will be included.</small>
        </p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat_exclude' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Exclude Categories:', 'simplisto' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cat_exclude' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cat_exclude' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat_exclude ); ?>" />
        <small>Comma separated list of category IDs to <strong>exclude</strong> in post query. e.g.: 1,16<br>If blank, no categories will be excluded.</small>
        </p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $vertical_sidebar_check, 'on' ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'vertical_sidebar_check' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'vertical_sidebar_check' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'vertical_sidebar_check' ); ?>"><?php _e('Select for Vertical Sidebar', 'simplisto'); ?></label></p>


         <?php
    }

    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']           = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['number_of_posts'] = absint( $new_instance['number_of_posts'] );
        $instance['number_of_words'] = absint( $new_instance['number_of_words'] );
        $instance['cat_include']     = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['cat_include'] );
        $instance['cat_exclude']     = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['cat_exclude'] );
        $instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] = isset( $new_instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) && ( 'on' === $new_instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) ? 'on' : 'off';
        return $instance;
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        /* Display the markup before the widget. */
        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }

        $number_of_posts = ( ! empty( $instance['number_of_posts'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number_of_posts'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number_of_posts ) {
            $number_of_posts = 5;
        }

        $number_of_words = ( ! empty( $instance['number_of_words'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number_of_words'] ) : 20;
        if ( ! $number_of_words ) {
            $number_of_words = 20;
        }

        // Convert comma separated string to array for use in WP_Query.
        $category_include = $instance['cat_include'];
        if ( $category_include ) {
            $category_include = explode( ',', $instance['cat_include'] );
        } else {
            $category_include = array();
        }

        // Convert comma separated string to array for use in WP_Query.
        $category_exclude = $instance['cat_exclude'];
        if ( $category_exclude ) {
            $category_exclude = explode( ',', $instance['cat_exclude'] );
        } else {
            $category_exclude = array();
        }

        $vertical_sidebar_check = isset( $instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) && ( 'on' === $instance[ 'vertical_sidebar_check' ] ) ? 'on' : 'off';

        /* Create a custom query and get the most recent x projects. */
        $queryArgs = array(
            'category__in' => $category_include,
            'category__not_in' => $category_exclude,
            /* Order by date. */
            'orderby' => 'date',
            /* Show all posts. */
            'posts_per_page' => $number_of_posts,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $queryArgs );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <ul class="unbullet<?php echo $vertical_sidebar_check === 'on' ? ' unbullet-v' : ''; ?>">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li class="snippet-box<?php echo $vertical_sidebar_check === 'on' ? ' vertical' : ''; ?>">
                            <div>
                                <!-- <img src="http://heightandweights.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Beautiful-Lindsey-Vonn.jpg" alt="" class="hundred"> -->
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'class' => 'hundred' ) ); ?>
                                <div class="snippet-text">
                                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(), $number_of_words , __( '&hellip;', 'simplisto' ) ); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?></a> -->
                        </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
        <?php endif;
        /* Display the markup after the widget. */
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

    add_action('widgets_init', function(){
        register_widget('chimp_post_widget');
    })
    ?>
```

Do you think is there any place where we can write the `apply_filters` or any other kind of sanitization that a novice like me has missed.

I think this post may be helpful to various beginners in implementing santization and other functions that are important for code quality.

Comment: WordPress has it's own set of [sanitization functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and usually, in widgets, themes, or plugins you would call `apply_filters()` to allow other users change the settings, arguments, or output. You don't usually see people using `apply_filters()` to allow other users to modify sanitization methods. So I'm a little confused on what you're asking about here, are you wanting input on where to put `apply_filters` to allow others to modify data or are you asking if there's any sanitization you may have missed?

Comment: My understanding about sanitization is that make the data safe at the time of feeding it in the database and retrieving it from the database? Is my understanding correct? I posted it with that perspective.

Comment: @howdy-mcgee sir, Are you there?

Comment: The question is, does your widget take any input from the users? You usually want to sanitize a data to make sure it's safe (other than escaping). If you don't get any input from the user, there's really no need to sanitize it for safety.

Answer (score 0):

I use these commands at the top of my functions.php in all child themes; it will sanitize all POST/GETs. Maybe there are better ways (and it might be redundant), but it appears to work for me.

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_GET  = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

But I am open to constructive criticism....